# Why does the frequency response H(f) exhibit conjugate symmetry in case of a linear system with real impulse response?

Tags: communication

The frequency response H(f) is a complex quantity. So, it can be expressed as:

$$H(f)=|H(f)|exp[j \beta (f)]$$

Why in case of linear system, having a real valued impulse response h(t), does the frequency response H(f) exhibit conjugate symmetry ie.

$$|H(f)|=|H(-f)|$$

$$\beta (f)=-\beta (-f)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of frequency response:

$$H(e^{jw}) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h[k] e^{-jkw}$$

Now take the complex conjugate of both sides.

$$H^{*}(e^{jw}) = \left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h[k] e^{-jkw}\right)^{*}$$

$$H^{*}(e^{jw}) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h[k] \left(e^{-jkw}\right)^{*}$$

$$H^{*}(e^{jw}) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h[k] e^{jkw}$$

$$H^{*}(e^{jw}) = H(e^{-jw})$$

Because h[n] is real, the complex conjugate only applies to the exponent term.

Answer (score 0):

The fourier transform has a property called the complex conjugate property:

$${\mathcal F}[x(t)] = X(j\omega) \implies {\mathcal F}[x^*(t)]=X^*(-j\omega)$$

You can find a proof of this property from the definition of the transform [here](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node2.html) among other sources.

If \$x(t)\$ is real-valued, then \$x(t)=x^*(t)\$, so we must have

$$X(j\omega)=X^*(-j\omega).$$

Answer (score 0):

Because frequency response H(f) is the Fourier transform of impulse response h(f), and Fourier transform of any real-valued function exhibits conjugate symmetry.